# Getting TypeError: $.ajax(...).done is not a function [Ajax, Jquery ]

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

In my Jquery, i am using Ajax and getting below error msg.

```
TypeError: $.ajax(...).done is not a function
[Break On This Error] ).success(function(response) {
```

I tired using success instead of done. but still getting same msg.

```
TypeError: $.ajax(...).success is not a function
[Break On This Error] ).success(function(response) {
```

sample piece of code is mentioned below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        alert('in get');
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                'contentId': contentId,
                'USER_ID': USER_ID,
                'actionType': 'GETRATING',
                'portletGuid': portletGuid
            },
            type: 'GET',
            url: ajaxRatingServlet,
            cache: false
        }).success(function (response) {
            getUserPreference(response);
        });
```

Comment: have you loaded jQuery..?? what version of jquery you are using..?

Comment: try using the latest version of jquery and use .done, should work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace your `success` with `done` or use success inside ajax function.

> An alternative construct to the success callback option, the [.done()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
>   method replaces the deprecated jqXHR.success() method.

**EG**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            'contentId': contentId,
            'USER_ID': USER_ID,
            'actionType': 'GETRATING',
            'portletGuid': portletGuid
        },
        type: 'GET',
        url: ajaxRatingServlet,
        cache: false
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
  });

 //or use success inside ajax as other answered

 $(document).ready(function() {
      alert('in get'); 
      $.ajax({ 
       data: { 'contentId':contentId, 'USER_ID':USER_ID, 'actionType':'GETRATING', 'portletGuid':portletGuid },
       type:'GET',
       url:ajaxRatingServlet,
       cache:false,
       success: function(response) { 
            getUserPreference(response);
           }
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

try using success function inside ajax function ,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      alert('in get'); 
      $.ajax({ 
       data: { 'contentId':contentId, 'USER_ID':USER_ID, 'actionType':'GETRATING', 'portletGuid':portletGuid },
       type:'GET',
       url:ajaxRatingServlet,
       cache:false,
       success: function(response) { 
            getUserPreference(response);
           }
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can used this Demo

There are some extra function which help you

[Nice Demo](http://www.bennadel.com/resources/presentations/jquery/demo21/)

```
                                 $(
function(){
    // Get a reference to the content div (into which we will load content).
    var jContent = $( "#content" );

    // Hook up link click events to load content.
    $( "a" ).click(
        function( objEvent ){
            var jLink = $( this );

            // Clear status list.
            $( "#ajax-status" ).empty();

            // Launch AJAX request.
            $.ajax(
                {
                    // The link we are accessing.
                    url: jLink.attr( "href" ),

                    // The type of request.
                    type: "get",

                    // The type of data that is getting returned.
                    dataType: "html",

                    error: function(){
                        ShowStatus( "AJAX - error()" );

                        // Load the content in to the page.
                        jContent.html( "<p>Page Not Found!!</p>" );
                    },

                    beforeSend: function(){
                        ShowStatus( "AJAX - beforeSend()" );
                    },

                    complete: function(){
                        ShowStatus( "AJAX - complete()" );
                    },

                    success: function( strData ){
                        ShowStatus( "AJAX - success()" );

                        // Load the content in to the page.
                        jContent.html( strData );
                    }
                }                           
                );

            // Prevent default click.
            return( false );                    
        }
        );

}
);
```

Comment: it allow you to fire some extra function before, after , success result............

Answer (score 0):

`success` and `error` aren't attributes of the object returned by the call to `$.ajax()`. Instead, you must pass them as configs in the call:

```
$.ajax({..., success: function(data){}})
```